# Save a csv file in python with datetime as filename

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I have the following code:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime

with open("D:/python/sursa_alimentare.csv", "w+") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["Descriere", "Pret"])`
```

Because I run this quite often, I want to save the csv file with a name that include the datetime format. 
Any help would appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried getting the current datetime, making a string out of it, and putting that string in the filename right before the `.csv`?

Comment: @Cristina, how do you want output looks ?

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `.strftime`

```
filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M.csv")

with open(filename, "w+") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Descriere", "Pret"])`
```

here is some details https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm

Comment: Thanh you, it works perfectly. Also, thanks for the tutorial. It is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using `datetime.now()` directly, as this will create `:` in the filename, which would fail if used on a Windows file system. Instead use [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to add the required formatting:

```
from datetime import datetime

filename = datetime.now().strftime('sursa_alimentare-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M.csv')

with open(filename, "w+") as f_output:
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
        csv_output.writerow(["Descriere", "Pret"])
```

Giving a filename such as:

```
sursa_alimentare-2018-03-05-09-01.csv
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works. Have a beautiful day :)

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forgot to click on the grey tick under the up/down arrows for one of the answers to select it as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might help you add datetime to your filename,

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime

file_name = 'sursa_alimentare-'+str(datetime.datetime.now())+'.csv'
with open(file_name, "w+") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["Descriere", "Pret"])
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution and it is perfect. Have a nice day.